# How To Allow Special Characters & Capital Letters In Wp Permalink?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

for some reason and to save my time i need this type of url structure in wordpress - http://www.spaste.com/p/?c=Ee7xgT5097
but in wordpress "?c=Ee7xgT5097"  become like this "cee7xgt5097"
I tried some wp plugin (Allow Accents and Special Characters, permalink manager) but didn't work for me the way i want . Any solution ?

Comment: You should be able to pass GET variables in a URL. However, in this case it looks like your link is being sanitized by WordPress. Can you show us how the link is being generated?

Answer (score 0):

For the Capital letter in Permalink, you can try this plugin. https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/